# Django Admin Login page - Python Crashes

Tags: python, django-admin, django-login, django-3.0

I am trying to login to admin url of the Django post creating superuser through command prompt. After i clicked log in button i am getting "Python has stopped working".

> Python Ver: 3.7.0 Django Ver: 3.0

- Step 1: Created website using django-admin command
- Step 2: Using runserver command verified Django Default home page is loading
- Step 3: Tried admin/ post creating super admin users.
- Step 4: Post Login button click, "Python Stopped working" error is displayed.

---

**What I tried to solve this issue without any success**

1. Verified through shell my created user is active, superadmin, is_staff and all are true

```
    from django.contrib.auth import authenticate

    u = authenticate(username="username", password="password")
```

2. Tried adding and removing `SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = False` in `settings.py`
3. Verifed `ALLOWED_HOSTS = []` in `settings.py`

   What should I do to see the admin page?

Comment: ALLOWED_HOSTS should be `['*']` to allow access from everywhere. But I doubt that caused "Python stopped working" error.

Comment: do you see any errors in the python service that is running django?

Comment: @SimasJoneliunas i got the below trace 

[06/Dec/2019 01:35:08] "POST /admin/login/?next=/admin/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0

Comment: if you open the debug window (for Firefox F12 -> network), to what url does your server redirect

any get request after that post?

Comment: @useruser00 I am facing the same problem right now. Every time I log in to admin url python stops working. Even the apps I was working on two days ago are not working now. Have you figured out a solution yet?

Comment: Hey! So I have uninstalled python and reinstalled it (version 3.8) and thankfully everything is working again.

Comment: @gelonida "POST /admin/login/?next=/admin/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0 this url is getting displayed in the command prompt.

Comment: @Hajar No luck with the issue.... still having same problem :(

Comment: I know how frustrating it's so I really hope you figure out a solution soon.

Comment: @Hajar Till yesterday i tried with Python 3.7.0, i upgraded python to 3.7.3 and the admin page opens smoothly as expected. Not sure any issue with 3.7.0 for django...

Comment: That's great! And yes, I think it has something to do with python 3.7.0 because when I used version 3.8 of python the admin page opened with me as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem with python 3.7.0 and Django 3.0 
I've solved it by upgrading the python to Python 3.7.6

`brew upgrade python3`

Then I faced some issues with links and venv and I had to reinstall my venv and Django. So, I hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same issue with Python 3.7.0 as well. Upgrading to Python 3.8.0 solves this.

Answer (score 1):

I had also facing the same issue i upgrade my python but problem is not with python it is occur by virtual  environment.
upgrade your virtual environment by running following command 
python -m venv --upgrade ./myvenv

Answer (score 1):

Same issue with Python 3.7.0 > fixed with Python 3.7.8

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. But I was using anaconda bundle. It doesn't allow you to update your python packages to minor versions like "3.7.X" or "3.8.X". So, I uninstalled the existing bundle and reinstalled it which comes with a 3.7.6 version of Python. That solved the issue of admin page crashing.

Or

You can install a new version of python (3.7.6 or above) and run your django application there.